# Cross Compile allJoyn on Ubuntu for RaspberryPI

Tags: cross-compiling, alljoyn

I am trying to cross-compile AllJoyn on Ubuntu 16.04 for RaspberryPI2. I followed steps mentioned https://wiki.allseenalliance.org/develop/building_and_running under section Linux Cross-Compiling.

When I try to compile AllJoyn using command 
`scons OS=openwrt CPU=openwrt BINDINGS=cpp,c,java WS=off BT=off ICE=off SERVICE="about,notification,controlpannel,config,onboarding,sample_apps"`
 
I get following error

```
    scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking c++ compiler support for -std=c++11 flag... Printing env dump...
{ 'CPATH': '/home/jha/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include',
  'HOME': '/home/jha',
  'LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/jha/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib:/home/jha/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/libexec',
  'PATH': '/home/jha/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin',
  'STAGING_DIR': '/home/jha/rpi/linux/usr'}
no
Checking c++ compiler support for -std=c++0x flag... Printing env dump...
{ 'CPATH': '/home/jha/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include',
  'HOME': '/home/jha',
  'LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/jha/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib:/home/jha/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/libexec',
  'PATH': '/home/jha/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin',
  'STAGING_DIR': '/home/jha/rpi/linux/usr'}
no
*** Compiler too old to build AllJoyn.  Aborting.
```

I modified the SConscript file under build_core/conf/openwrt to print env variables right before checking the compiler.

To verify that my compiler is not an outdated compiler, I tried following

1. Created a file named "test.cc" with one line in it `int main(void) { return 0; }`
2. Compiled the file using command `/home/jha/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -std=c++11 -o ../test ../test.cc`
3. File compiles without any error
4. Version of arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ is 4.9.3

Following are values of environment variables I set, before running the scons command

```
HOST_HOME="/home/jha/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf"
TARGET_PREFIX="arm-linux-gnueabihf-"
export TARGET_PATH="${HOST_HOME}/bin"
export TARGET_CC="${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc"
export TARGET_CPPFLAGS=""
export TARGET_CFLAGS="-I${HOST_HOME}/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include"
export CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11"
export TARGET_CXX="${TARGET_PREFIX}g++"
export TARGET_LINK=$TARGET_CC
export TARGET_LINKFLAGS="-L${HOST_HOME}/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib -L${HOST_HOME}/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/libexec"
export TARGET_LDFLAGS=$TARGET_LINKFLAGS
export TARGET_AR="${TARGET_PREFIX}ar"
export TARGET_RANLIB="${TARGET_PREFIX}ranlib"
export STAGING_DIR="/home/jha/rpi/linux/usr"
export CROSS_PREFIX=$TARGET_PREFIX
export CROSS_PATH=$TARGET_PATH
export CROSS_CFLAGS="$TARGET_CFLAGS -march=armv7 "
export CROSS_LINKFLAGS=$TARGET_LINKFLAGS
export CROSS_COMPILE=$TARGET_PREFIX
```

I am not able to cross-compile AllJoyn for RaspberryPI2 on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Any pointers in right direction will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out cross compiling AllJoyn for ARM, following are the steps http://itisprakash.blogspot.com/2016/05/cross-compile-alljoyn-for-raspberrypi.html